# Use encrypted with symmetric columns in ssas cubes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

We use SQL server database and some of our text field in tables use symmetric encryption is there a way to open encrypt key before processing the data so the data is shown decrypted in cubes?
We need open keys before fetching data by SSAS.
I also read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wwerner1/2012/12/04/column-encrypted-in-database-but-decrypted-in-clear-text-in-cube/) thread but its not exactly the way we want to do it.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. If the data is encrypted, it is encrypted for a reason. Storing it unencrypted in the cube means that security on the field is lost, as any one with access to that cube can read the original data.

Comment: I don't any see any supported solution for doing that in SQL SSAS.

Comment: SSAS Multidimensional or Tabular? If Tabular you can use a stored proc as the source for an SSAS table. But not in Multidimensional. You would have to do a table valued function if you needed to execute multiple statements as the source for a table in SSAS Multidimensional.

Comment: Why is that blog post you mentioned not what you want to do?